# Executing the Eclipse generate javadoc from the command line

Tags: java, eclipse, cmd

I have a case where I would like to generate a javadoc in the following manner.

- I would like to generate the javadoc for public methods for the entire project
- I would like to generate a javadoc for protected methods of a single class.

This is very easy to do using the Generate Javadoc tool in Eclipse, but it has been requested that Javadoc generation for this case use the command line or batch script instead of the Eclipse GUI.

After reading through the following link

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#runningjavadoc

I understand how I can use the javadoc tool from the command line but it does not tell me how I would select which type of methods to document, and it also appears that I will have to list each class.

My questions are as follows,

- Is there a way to run the Eclipse style Javadoc generation tool from the command line? If so where can I find and example of how to do this.
- If there isn't a way to do the above, is there a way to tell the javadoc tool to go through each package and document the classes within recursively?
- Is there a way to tell the javadoc tool what type of methods to document, public vs protected vs etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let eclipse generate an ant build file. Then you can use this ant build file from the command line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

from the javadoc helptext you can use these flags/parameters:

```
-public                   Show only public classes and members
-protected                Show protected/public classes and members (default)
-package                  Show package/protected/public classes and members
-private                  Show all classes and members
-help                     Display command line options and exit
-doclet <class>           Generate output via alternate doclet
-docletpath <path>        Specify where to find doclet class files
-sourcepath <pathlist>    Specify where to find source files
-classpath <pathlist>     Specify where to find user class files
-exclude <pkglist>        Specify a list of packages to exclude
-subpackages <subpkglist> Specify subpackages to recursively load
```

Alternatively, you can use a build tool like ant or maven to generate the javadoc for you which have nice wrapped functions.  Here is the ant javadoc target for one of my projects:

```
<target name="javadoc" description = "generate javadoc from source">
    <delete dir="javadoc" verbose ="true"/>
    <javadoc packagenames ="my.app.*"               
            sourcepathref = "javadoc.sourcepath"
            author ="true"
            destdir = "javadoc"
            windowtitle = "${project-name} API"
            linksource= "yes"
            overview="${src}/overview-summary.html"
        access="public">                    



    </javadoc>
    </target>
```