# Get command line for Javadoc generated via Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

Eclipse has a really nice wizard to generate Javadoc for selected classes. However, is it possible to get the command line that was used by Eclipse to generate the Javadoc?

I already had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18063880/3429133) which says that it is possible to generate an Ant script, but I haven't found a way to get the actual command line. I know that there is a `man` page respectively a documention of the `javadoc` command, but rather figuring this out by mself, I thought maybe there is a way to get the commands/options from Eclipse (or Ant).

Answer (score 0):

You just have to look at [Oracle's documentation about Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/javadoc/javadoc-command.htm#JSJAV-GUID-EAAAE17F-E540-42A0-B22B-4D2B2FD3E4D2)

The command line should have this structure:

> ```
> javadoc [options] [packagenames] [sourcefiles] [@files]
> ```
>
> ***options***
>
> Specifies command-line options, separated by spaces. See Options for javadoc, Extended Options, Standard doclet Options, and
>   Nonstandard Options Provided by the Standard doclet.
>
> ***packagenames***
>
> Specifies names of packages that you want to document, separated by spaces, for example java.lang java.lang.reflect java.awt. If you
>   want to also document the subpackages, then use the -subpackages
>   option to specify the packages.
>
> By default, javadoc looks for the specified packages in the current directory and subdirectories. Use the -sourcepath option to
>   specify the list of directories where to look for packages.
>
> ***sourcefiles***
>
> Specifies names of Java source files that you want to document, separated by spaces, for example Class.java Object.java Button.java.
>   By default, javadoc looks for the specified classes in the current
>   directory. However, you can specify the full path to the class file
>   and use wildcard characters, for example
>   /home/src/java/awt/Graphics*.java. You can also specify the path
>   relative to the current directory.
>
> ***@files***
>
> Specifies names of files that contain a list of javadoc command options, package names, and source file names in any order.

Comment: I know that there's a `man` page, but rather than figuring out myself what commands and options I need to get the results that I want, I thought maybe there's a way to get the command line from Eclipse.